# Overcoming the negative instantaneous frequencies from Hilbert transform

Tags: hilbert-transform, instantaneous-frequency

how to avoid negative frequencies that can be obtained from instantaneous frequency estimation using Hilbert transform?

Here is what I am doing:

1. compute analytic signal, `X = hilbert(x)`;
2. from analytic signal, unwrap the instantaneous phase
3. calculate instantaneous frequency from derivation (`np.diff`) of instantaneous phase

The problem I have is that the instantaneous frequency can contains negative frequencies (e.g. chirp signal).

This issue is also well descriped her:

[Negative instantaneous frequency with hilbert transform using scipy hilbert](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73531/negative-instantaneous-frequency-with-hilbert-transform-using-scipy-hilbert)

[Hilbert Huang Transform: Negative value in instantaneous frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42355/hilbert-huang-transform-negative-value-in-instantaneous-frequency)

The best solution seems to be descriped here:

[Overcoming the negative frequencies - Instantaneous frequency and amplitude estimation using Osculating Circle method](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265026536_Overcoming_the_negative_frequencies_-_Instantaneous_frequency_and_amplitude_estimation_using_Osculating_Circle_method)

and here:

[Instantaneous frequency estimation using Osculating Circle Method](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254011228_Instantaneous_frequency_estimation_using_Osculating_Circle_Method)

An other matlab code snipped is posted here, but it has no results:

[InstantFrequencyOCM​ethod](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48924-instantfrequencyocmethod)

The question is, how to calculate the velocity vector of the particle and the Osculating Circle method from the analytic signal (in matlab or python)?

Thanks,
Tobias

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the paper you attached to get the corrected Instantaneous Phase and Frequency. So as far as I understood, the velocity vector is the derivation of the analytical signal, so here is the step I tried:

1. Compute the analytical signal,

X=scipy.signal.hilbert(x)

2. Compute its derivation to get the velocity vector, here I used second order derivatite, as the first order still gives me negative frequency in the final result.

def second_derivative(amplitude, sampling_rate):

```
d_xt=[]
for i in range (len(amplitude)-2):
    d_xt.append((amplitude[i+2]-amplitude[i])/2)
return(d_xt)
```

dX= second_derivative(X, fs)

note:Based on the type of your data, maybe you want to use different type of derivation to maybe deal with the noisy gradient.

3. Compute the corrected angle, corrected_phase= np.unwrap(np.angle(dX)-0.5*np.pi)
4. Compute the instantaneous frequency
   freq= np.diff(corrected_phase)

Answer (score -1):

Don’t unwrap phase as bounded, but unwrap it as always increasing (or `delta(ph)>=0`).

Comment: I am using numpy.unwrap and matlab and GNU Octave unwrap. Should I implement a different unwrap?

Comment: The instantaneous frequency is the difference in phase of the current sample to the previous sample of the analytic signal.  I don't think it's a good idea treat some small negative quantity $-|\Delta \phi|$ as a value close to $2\pi$.